# Using awsiotsdk when subscribing to a topic with QoS.EXACTLY_ONCE, encountering AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm following [the example pub/sub](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/1c0cf4554e294fff64b91b7152bc0f2d930175d4/samples/pubsub.py#L79) in `awsiotsdk`.

```
# boilerplate setup code omitted
self.mqtt_connection = awsiot.mqtt_connection_builder.websockets_with_default_aws_signing(...)
connect_future = self.mqtt_connection.connect()
print('Connected: ', connect_future.result())
```

```
[OUTPUT] Connected:  {'session_present': True}
```

Everything through the connection process looks good. Next I subscribe to a topic:

```
def mycallback(*args, **kwargs):
  print("mycallback: ", args, kwargs)

subscribe_future, packet_id = self.mqtt_connection.subscribe(
  topic='test/topic',
  callback=mycallback,
  qos=awscrt.mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE
)
subscribe_future.result()
```

The above code works, I can later publish and receive the message successfully.

However if I change the QoS to `EXACTLY_ONCE` I get the following errors:

```
In _on_connection_interrupted: (), {'connection': <awscrt.mqtt.Connection object at 0x7f804acfea40>, 'error': AwsCrtError(name='AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP', message='The connection was closed unexpectedly.', code=5134)}
In _on_connection_resumed: (), {'connection': <awscrt.mqtt.Connection object at 0x7f804acfea40>, 'return_code': <ConnectReturnCode.ACCEPTED: 0>, 'session_present': True}
In _on_connection_interrupted: (), {'connection': <awscrt.mqtt.Connection object at 0x7f804acfea40>, 'error': AwsCrtError(name='AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP', message='The connection was closed unexpectedly.', code=5134)}
In _on_connection_resumed: (), {'connection': <awscrt.mqtt.Connection object at 0x7f804acfea40>, 'return_code': <ConnectReturnCode.ACCEPTED: 0>, 'session_present': True}
<repeats a few more lines>
```

What is the issue with EXACTLY_ONCE? It seems like the QoS I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EXACTLY_ONCE`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-python/blob/main/awscrt/mqtt.py#L39) (MQTT QOS level 2) is not currently supported by the AWS IoT Core server. This is mentioned in [the source](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-python/blob/main/awscrt/mqtt.py#L39):

```
QoS 2 - Exactly once delivery
This is the highest quality of service, for use when neither loss nor
duplication of messages are acceptable. There is an increased overhead
associated with this quality of service.

Note that, while this client supports QoS 2, the AWS IoT Core server
does not support QoS 2 at time of writing (May 2020).
```

and in the [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html#mqtt-qos):

> The MQTT protocol defines a third level of QoS, level 2, but AWS IoT does not support it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Wow, what an error message for, "this feature isn't supported." :)

Comment: Yep it's not ideal however kind of mandated by the [MQTT spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref381955543) with disconnection the only real action on an error - "If the Client or Server encounters a Transient Error while processing an inbound Control Packet it MUST close the Network Connection on which it received that Control Packet". I assume there is a possibility that they may add QOS 2 support at some point in the future so want to support it in their libraries.